# Do evaluations have adjoints?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories. Consider the functor category $C^D$. Suppose $C$ has all small limits. Then $C^D$ has all small limits too, and these are computed pointwise for the following reason:

*For each object $d\in D$, the evaluation functor $C^D\to C$, which maps a functor $F\colon D\to C$ to $F(D)$, preserves small limits and small colimits.*

This suggests the following question:

> Do the evaluation functors always have a left adjoint *and* a right adjoint?

In particular, consider the category of simplicial sets. If $d=[0]$ is the terminal object in the simplex category (thus initial object in $D=\Delta^\mathrm{op}$), then the evaluation functor sends a simplicial set $S_\bullet$ to $S_0$. Indeed, this functor has a left adjoint, the functor sending a set $S$ to the simplicial set that is constant $S$. But I don't know whether it has a right adjoint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the evaluation functors have adjoints whenever $D$ is small and $C$ is complete/cocomplete (for right/left adjoints), the adjoints are then precisely *Kan extensions* along the functor $1\to D$ picking out the object being evaluated at.

In the case of simplicial sets, the right adjoint to evaluation at the $0$-simplex is the 'codiscrete simplicial set' functor that sends a set $S$ to the simplicial set having points of $S$ as vertices, and exactly $1$ $n$-simplex for every $(n+1)$-tuple of points.